# Parsing JSON with parent container ( ) in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'm getting a JSON response that looks like this:

```
YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback(
{
    "ResultSet": {
        "Query": "ya",
        "Result": [
            {
                "symbol": "YHOO",
                "name": "Yahoo! Inc.",
                "exch": "NMS",
                "type": "S",
                "exchDisp": "NASDAQ"
            },
            {
                "symbol": "AUY",
                "name": "Yamana Gold, Inc.",
                "exch": "NYQ",
                "type": "S",
                "exchDisp": "NYSE"
            },
            {
                "symbol": "YZC",
                "name": "Yanzhou Coal Mining Co. Ltd.",
                "exch": "NYQ",
                "type": "S",
                "exchDisp": "NYSE"
            },
            {
                "symbol": "YRI.TO",
                "name": "YAMANA GOLD INC COM NPV",
                "exch": "TOR",
                "type": "S",
                "exchDisp": "Toronto"
            },
            {
                "symbol": "8046.TW",
                "name": "NAN YA PRINTED CIR TWD10",
                "exch": "TAI",
                "type": "S",
                "exchDisp": "Taiwan"
            },
            {
                "symbol": "600319.SS",
                "name": "WEIFANG YAXING CHE 'A'CNY1",
                "exch": "SHH",
                "type": "S",
                "exchDisp": "Shanghai"
            },
            {
                "symbol": "1991.HK",
                "name": "TA YANG GROUP",
                "exch": "HKG",
                "type": "S",
                "exchDisp": "Hong Kong"
            },
            {
                "symbol": "1303.TW",
                "name": "NAN YA PLASTIC TWD10",
                "exch": "TAI",
                "type": "S",
                "exchDisp": "Taiwan"
            },
            {
                "symbol": "0294.HK",
                "name": "YANGTZEKIANG",
                "exch": "HKG",
                "type": "S",
                "exchDisp": "Hong Kong"
            },
            {
                "symbol": "YAVY",
                "name": "Yadkin Valley Financial Corp.",
                "exch": "NMS",
                "type": "S",
                "exchDisp": "NASDAQ"
            }
        ]
    }
}
)
```

My problem is when I try to parse it into an NSDictionary or NSArray.

```
 NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error: &e];

if (!jsonArray) {
    NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@", e);
} else {
    for(NSDictionary *item in jsonArray) {
        NSLog(@"Item: %@", item);
    }
}
```

I get this error: `Error parsing JSON: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Invalid value around character 0.)`

I'm guessing because the response is given in this container:

```
YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback()
```

Is this so? What is an easy way to clean this up for proper parsing? Thanks

Comment: That appears to be JSONP.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to strip the parts from the string. Dirty but it works.

```
    NSString *resultString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //Strip: YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback( )
    NSRange JSONRange = NSMakeRange(39, [resultString length] - 40);
    NSString *JSONString = [resultString substringWithRange:JSONRange];
```